# Folland's real analysis, total variation of complex measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm confused about the following highlighted part about total variation of complex measure in Folland's real analysis:

[image]
[image]

How can we obtain $f$ by taking $\mu=|\upsilon_r| + |\upsilon_i|$ for Theorem 3.12?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The $\lambda$ you get from Theorem 3.12 is $0$ because $\nu <<\mu$ in this case.

Comment: I think this is a very obtuse way of defining the total variation.

Comment: Given any complex measure $\nu$, take $\mu=|\nu_r| + |\nu_i|$, then, by Theorem 3.12, there is a complex measure and $f \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $\lambda \perp \mu$ and $d\nu = d\lambda + f d\mu$.  But $\nu \ll \mu$, so $\lambda = 0$. So $d\nu = f d\mu$. So, for any complex measure $\nu$, it is always possible to define $|\nu| = |f|d\mu$.